# Does combining two queries with UNION ALL require an alias?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with identical structure, identical `userid` values but otherwise different data

I'm trying to do a query that will give me a combined list of results from both tables, on the basis of the `userid`

Table 1:

| userid | time | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 1342 | New York |

Table 2:

| userid | time | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 1800 | New Jersey |

And so I previously had two separate queries and would run my PHP based on the results of each separate query

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE userid = 18
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE userid = 18
```

But now, I would like to simply combine them all into one result set, since the structure between `table1` and `table2` are identical

So I tried the following query

```
SELECT * FROM (
                (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE userid = 18)
                                 UNION ALL
                (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE userid = 18)
              )
```

this results in the following error:

```
Every derived table must have its own alias
```

I guess I'm confused on why this would need an alias, since I just want the combined result.

I changed my query to:

```
SELECT * FROM (
                (SELECT * FROM table1 as P WHERE userid = 18)
                                 UNION ALL
                (SELECT * FROM table2 as Q WHERE userid = 18)
              ) as R
```

And this does ***seem*** to work, but I'm confused as to why and if this is ultimately correct or if i'm something losing or altering my data by doing that

Comment: It's correct.  There is some unnecessary detail, like the `AS P` and `AS Q`, plus the `( )`s around the tables in the `UNION`.  The `R` correlation name is required by the standard, but some databases may not require it.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3a8911381d07b220b1051f40c05e3e4   I suppose this should be an anwer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every derived table, i.e. subquery in the `FROM` clause, must have an alias. Assigning an alias for a derived table does not change anything in the source table. It's only for the current query.

As a side note, your example could be written more simply:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE userid = 18
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE userid = 18;
```

In this form, the derived table and the individual table aliases are not necessary for this example, but perhaps the example in your question is simplified from your real case.